# Allow editing of only a single field of a node in Panels or a block

Tags: blocks, panels, nodes

I am working with drupal 7. I have organic groups and cck set up. I want users to be able to only edit the group audience field in an organic group but nothing else. Is there a way where I can only add a group audience edit field to a panel or a block ?

I looked at the form block module, but that provides access to the complete content edit page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use the [Field API Pane Editor](http://drupal.org/project/fape).  Though the name may be unusual, the module

> adds a contextual link to the Entity Field panel pane which allows that field to be edited without having to visit the entity's edit page.

Earl Miles introduced this module at [DrupalCon 2012](http://denver2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/whats-new-panels-universe) (see 13:30 in the linked video).

Comment: Hi Thanks for that module, I hope its really helpful, but can you explain me how to use it ?

Comment: Actually, I got it working, but only the admin was able to edit it. How do i make the contextual edit link for the field visible for everyone ??

Comment: Did you check the permissions?  You must make sure everyone you want to do edits has edit access and they may need a permission for the Field API Pane Editor module as well.

Comment: Yea I checked it, did you work on the module before ? If so can you let me know what exactly i need to do, just in case i'm missing something.

Comment: Ohh Sorry, but i got it, i need to enable permissions for contextual links to members.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

If you allow your users access to the group edit form, they will only see the fields that you have selected to be editable using Field Permissions.

Use that in conjunction with the form block module as you've suggested and you should get the effect that you're looking for.

Comment: Ohh the form block only works on node creation pages but not on note editing pages.

Comment: also the field settings cannot be applied to default fields like title. Is there a way where I can hide or not allow the user to edit the title ?

Comment: I think the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module might be able to help you out with that

Answer (score 2):

Clive has suggested a good solution, but I will adress the Panels part of the question as this also comes up in the issue queue every now and then.

Unfortunately, the answer is that, "yes you can", but you should not. Panels will allow you to render a single form edit field, but form api will does not support this, and so saving will not behave as you intended.